# can we use cursor for a UPDATE query?

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql, bind-variables

Can we declare and open a cursor for UPDATE query also or is it only for SELECT queries?

```
   EXEC SQL PREPARE S FROM :query;
   EXEC SQL DECLARE C CURSOR FOR S;
   DbUtilT::set_bind_variables(bind_dp,&paramList);
   EXEC SQL OPEN C USING DESCRIPTOR bind_dp;
   EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND GOTO end_update_loop;
   EXEC SQL FETCH C USING DESCRIPTOR bind_dp;
   EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK;
```

Is this fine? Or should we use cursor only for SELECT statments then how do we execute UPDATE queries?

Comment: @Alex - Yes this is in Pro*C

Answer (score 1):

If `query` is something like:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE ... FOR UPDATE OF id
```

then you can do:

```
...
EXEC SQL FETCH C USING DESCRIPTOR bind_dp;
EXEC SQL UPDATE mytable SET id = <something> WHERE CURRENT OF C;
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean though; you don't have to use a cursor to do an update, you can do:

```
EXEC SQL UPDATE mytable SET id = <something> WHERE ...;
```

... or the equivalent prepared statement.

Have I completely misunderstood the question?

Comment: Ya thats right when we donot have bind variables in the query.
If i am using bind variables in the query..
 Update <tablename> set <columnname>=:BIND_VAR1 where <columnname2>=:BINDVAR2 and <columnname3>=:BINDVAR3

how to go by?